# WP REST API get all posts (or customs posts) for a React app

Tags: json

A friend is developing a React frontend which should retrieve all posts of a certain the custom post type from my WP site.

Which API url allows you to retrieve more than 100 posts?

Comment: The official one, as long [as you paginate the results](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/). Which is usually a good practice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the custom posts need to have the `'show_in_rest' => true,` parameter set on post registration - see [Adding REST API Support For Custom Content Types](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/) for more detailed instructions.

Secondly, I then usually navigate to `yoursiteaddress.com/wp-json/` for example https://blog.ted.com/wp-json/ - there you'll see a play-book for all the routes you can play with in your React app. Check your REST route exists as you think it should.

Thirdly, read the page that @kero mentioned above in the comments - [Using the REST API - Pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/). This will, combined, tell you the full route you'd want to use along with the parameters that you'd want to be applying.

For example your first request URL might look something like this
`/wp/v2/custom_post?per_page=10&status=publish`

Your second page
`/wp/v2/custom_post?per_page=10&status=publish&page=2`

...and so on.